# Server goes down when deleting a directory with too many files

Tags: nginx, debian, plesk

I have a directory that contains about 1,5 millions php session files. When I try to delete it with `rm -rf session/`, after few minutes my website goes down with error 504 gateway timeout nginx. I have to restart it every time to get it to work.

Same with find command `find /full/path/tmp/sessions -name "sess_*" -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;`

Does anyone know how to safely delete these files?

OS : Debian 8.11 with PLESK.

Comment: I would expect a _Argument list too long_ error.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried to delete the folder with rm -rf sesions/ instead of rm -rf sessions/*

Comment: Try deleting a smaller number of files and repeat until they have all gone.

Comment: @RichardSmith Good idea if I know how to write a shell script to do it

Comment: The files must have some kind of alphanumeric sequence, you just need to select a small enough number that the OS can manage, e.g. `rm sessions/abcd1234*` and then repeat until all the files are gone. It may be laborious, but quicker than writing and testing a shell script.